# Message: mkdir(): Permission denied on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, mkdir

i have error when creating folder by using `mkdir()` on my codeigniter getting this error:

> Message: mkdir(): Permission denied

and this my code

```
$path = './upload_file/';
$idtrx = $_POST['id_trx'];
$dir = $path.$idtrx;
mkdir($dir,0777,TRUE);
```

can anyone  helps me??

Comment: You use `$dir`, but it isn't defined anywhere. Try it with `$path` instead.

Comment: i had define but it same

Comment: maybe you don't actually have permission!

Comment: Check the permission of parent folder...

Comment: Yes, the `$path = './upload_file/';` need write rights!

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
$file_path = FCPATH.'upload_file/'.$_POST['id_trx'];

if(!is_dir($file_path)) @mkdir($file_path, 0777, true);
```

Comment: If you are runnig in Problems with the CodeIgniter constant `FCPATH` try this:

`define('FCPATH', str_replace('\\', '/', __DIR__).'/');//or dirname(__FILE__) for PHP < 5.3`

Comment: @adilbo dear i think correct place of this comment is on question' comment section not here

Comment: Maybe you are right, but in the question FCPATH is not used, so i comment your fine answer ;-)